# When is the best moment to execute SonarQube

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, code-analysis

I´m starting to define my software lifecycle with Jenkins Pipelines but I have a doubt with SonarQube.

When is the best moment to execute SonarQube? Before compile the source code or after with the generated artifact?.

I'm a bit lost with this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the best moment to analyze is after compilation. Why?

- SonarSource analyzers (SonarJava, SonarJS, SonarCFamily, ...) assume compilable code
- Some analyzers (SonarJava) use byte code as part of the analysis

So in general you'll get both a better experience and a better analysis if you compile first.

Comment: Thanks you very much! your answer has been very useful! :)